# Make content DIV overlap header and footer

Tags: css, html, overlap

I'm having some issues with creating this effect with CSS:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMBmg.jpg

Basically, I want my content div to float on top and slightly overlap both the header and the footer elements. I've played around with some absolute positioning but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go. I want a responsive solution that works for all devices and screen sizes. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you want the content area's height to be determined? by the content or fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it.

If this is your HTML:

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Apply the following CSS:

```css
.header, .footer {
    height: 100px; /* not strictly needed... */
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.content {
    width: 50%; /* for example... */
    height: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.header {
    margin-bottom: -25px;
}
.footer {
    margin-top: -25px;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You can see the demo  at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/CNnay/

You set up three block level elements for the header, content and footer.

Apply negative margins to the bottom of the header and the top of the footer to
create the offset effect.

Finally, apply `z-index` to `.content` to tweak the stacking order so that the 
content block is painted over the footer block.

In this layout, the content block will expand vertically as you add more content.

The results looks like:

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `position:fixed` or `z-index:2000` of your `div` class

i have created this http://jsfiddle.net/RVnU7/1/